# Erro ao utilizar numeral.js em aplicação Asp.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando converter os dados da tabela para o valor monetário correto, e estou utilizando o numeral.js, tenho o seguinte script

```
@section scripts{

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.bootgrid.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/numeral/numeral.min.js"></script>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquerybootgrid")
    <script src="~/Scripts/Projeto/ControlarGrid.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">        

        numeral.language("pt-br");

        var controller = "Produtos";
        var urlListar = "@Url.Action("Listar")";
        $(document).ready(configurarControles);
    </script>
}
```

onde tenho uma pasta script ... e uma language com o *pt-br* para utilizar como padrão, mas quando ele inicia o script ocorre um erro logo no `numeral.language("pt-br")` levando em consideração que estou chamando o arquivo *numerao.min.js*

Comment: Que erro aparece? Abra o console do navegador e analise o erro lá.

Comment: Ocorre o seguinte erro Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Produtos:315 Uncaught TypeError: numeral.languages is not a function
    at Produtos:315 ... mas isso se da por conta do numeral ... pois se eu tirar ele, funciona normalmente

Comment: Deu falha ao carregar o arquivo JS do Numeral, consequentemente a variável `numeral` não tem a função `language`. Verifique se está carregando o script certinho na página.

Comment: Bom quando eu vou em source pelo navegador, aparece a pasta numeral e dentro só está aparecendo o numeral.min.js os outros arquivos não estão sendo carregados e nem o language

Comment: Cade a referencia no HTML do arquivo "language"? Pelo que eu entendi, a função `language` já é do arquivo "numeral.min.js".

Comment: Mas eu tenho que faz também uma chamada para o language dentro desse html? para ai sim poder utulizar o numeral.language?

Comment: <script src="~/Scripts/numeral/languages.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/numeral/languages/pt-br.js"></script> Devo realizar também essas chamadas? e mesmo se eu fizer isso o erro continua a persistir ...

Comment: Se você precisa usar o "languages.min.js", claro que tem que importar ele na página HTML. Agora o erro da função `numeral.language` pode estar atrelado a esses dois scripts, então coloque a referencia dos dois na página e teste novamente.